# How to listen to generic Kafka consumer

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I am looking for a solution where there are multiple topics created in Kafka server and based on another application, it will try to publish a message from any producer, but we don't know how to start respective consumer based on the producer.

The current solution which we have implemented is We have started all the consumer and all will listen and when any producer publishes message it will be received by appropriate consumer and this is not the efficient way to achieve it. Does anyone have a better solution?

EX: Topics are India, Australia, Singapore

Here I don't know from which country I will get a message, so I need to listen to all the Topics to get a message from any topic. is there any efficient way to do this?

Comment: Why do you need topics per country instead of using partitions per country in a single topic? Otherwise, of course you'll need to read from all topics

Comment: If there have 100's of topics in future and listening to all the topics is not a correct way. is there a better way to achieve this? . I hope I am not the only one struggling for this

Comment: Like I said, use partitions of one to several topics that you can target and assign consumers to. Otherwise, dump topics into a database where you can actually build/query using different index fields

Answer (score 0):

Finally I added all the required topics in a configuration file and I am listening to all the topics added in the configuration file and this is how I am using it service as generic consumer which listen to all topics